# How to create a temp table in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, temp, teradata-aster

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TEMP FACT TABLE new_table  DISTRIBUTE BY hash(a.var3) as
SELECT (YEAR(a.var1) - b.var2), a.var3
FROM d.data1 a, c.data2 b
WHERE (YEAR(var1) - var2) > 40
;

GO
SELECT * FROM age_DRG;
END;
```

I am not sure what is wrong with this code.  I keep getting this error

```
"Executed as Single statement.  Failed [34 : HY000] [AsterData][ASTERJDBCDSII](34) NOTICE: current transaction is aborted, queries ignored until end of transaction block () 
Elapsed time = 00:00:00.016 

STATEMENT 1: BEGIN;
CREATE Statement failed. "
```

Comment: There's no **GO** in Aster, this is Transact SQL syntax.

Comment: what do I use instead of go?

Comment: I can't test right now, but you might simply remove it.

Comment: hmm tried that and it gave me the same error.

Comment: Then remove the BEGIN/END, too. Do you really want to do it in a single transaction, why?

Comment: that doesn't seem to work either, im just trying to run the first part, but have had no success.

Comment: I think you still need to declare your columns in your temp table, as in `CREATE TEMP FACT TABLE new_table (<col1 int>,...) DISTRIBUTE BY...`.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no such function YEAR, you can use date_trunc('year', somedate) instead
2. You do not need to use "FACT" keyword, Aster will understand it by distribution type
3. dnoeth right, there is no GO keyword in Aster
4. I would recommend you to use joins to be more precise, because Aster was designed to calculate data on worker side and, i think, joins will be more "readable" for Aster.